# Как сделать пагинацию на android?

Tags: php, java, android

Добрый день, собственно задача такова: есть база данных, в ней кроется огрмное количество данных, естественно при отправке гет запроса сервер(php) выдает огромное количество данных и в клиенте(андроид) это должно как-то отразиться, но во первых это огромная нагрузка на сервер, а во вторых нагрузка на трафик, поэтому выдача полной бд и отображение ее в клиенте с помощью одного запроса - плохая идея.

Как я вижу решение данной проблемы? Сделать пагинацию , то отображение,например 10 элементов на клиенте, листаем вниз, еще какие-то определенные элементы докачиваются и т.д. Но для этого нужно чтобы и сервер выдавал не сразу все данные, а кусками, например по 10 элементов.

Как это все реализовать? В какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: в сторону запросса к базе данных на сервере

Comment: Какая БД используется?

Comment: за "докачку" элементов для отображения отвечает адаптер, так что тут можно особо не волноваться, ну а с запросами к серверу и их управлением придется поработать..

Comment: @Chubatiy MySql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо:

1. При запросе из приложения к серверу отсылать ему номер страницы.
2. Скрипт принимает этот номер и делает запрос к бд учитывая этот номер и кол-во элементов на страницу.
3. И отправляет данные приложению.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42789/discussion-on-answer-by------android).

Answer (score 0):

Так ты же сам и рассказал как всё это сделать !
Первый запрос делаем `Select Top 10 ... Order by SortField` при переходе на следующую порцию добавляем `Where SortField > &Last1SortField`